# My .fetchall() isn't updating on my Flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

This coe should show all records currently in the database, but it does not. When the page is reloaded, it does not show the latest rows added to the data base.

```
mod = Blueprint('home', __name__)
conn = engine.connect()

def grabData():
    query = text(
        "SELECT * FROM "
            "users "
        "ORDER BY id DESC "
    )
    rows = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    return rows

@mod.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', result=grabData())
```

*MySQL Workbench* shows that the new rows are there. After restarting the flask application, new rows are displayed.

I've also tried putting the query inside `home()` but that did not work either. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it does not work? If the data in the database does not change, *"a fresh set of data"* will always be the same as well.

Comment: I have a code that adds a record to the database, and when I refresh the page it does not give me the latest set of rows.

Comment: But maybe that code which adds a record to the database does not work? Do you `COMMIT` your changes?

Comment: I'm looking at the database, I see the row in the database....

Comment: Which database? How do you look at it? What happens if you restart the database? What ahppens if you restart the flask application?

Comment: If I restart the flask application then it gives me the new rows from the DB. I'm looking at the database through MySQL Workbench.... I can even manually add a row and it still won't show.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Try adding `print(rows)` before `return rows` to see what is actually executed and returned.

Comment: Are you sure the browser isn't using cached data? And that the server isn't returning a "304 Not modified"?

Comment: @TheWorstOne, If you will open it manually, yes, you have to close it manually. I don't recommend you to handle database connection by yourself. Take a look to [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: I am already using SQLAlchemy, I'm just using Raw SQL rather than some of the modifiers that it offers.

Answer (score 0):

I first off want to thank everyone for the comments, I have found the answer and I was hoping the user @davidism would've posted it but I guess I will but this is full credits to him.

So his comment was and I quote, "Don't open the connection globally, open it for each request". So what did I do? I only opened the db connection per each request and that actually solved my issue.

Instead of the code on the original post, this is what I ended up doing to make it work.

```
mod = Blueprint('home', __name__)

def grabData():
    conn = engine.connect()
    query = text(
        "SELECT * FROM "
            "users "
        "ORDER BY id DESC "
    )
    rows = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

@mod.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', result=grabData())
```